# corona sdk / solar2d multiple moving objects

Tags: lua, coronasdk, solar2d

I have problems with making multiple objects with random movement speed.
For example, I need to make 1000 objects and move them with random speed in random direction.

OOP aproach doesn't work, but in love2d it works without any problems.

```
local displayWidth = display.contentWidth
local displayHeight = display.contentHeight

particle = {}
particle.__index = particle

ActiveParticle = {}

function particle.new()
  instance = setmetatable({}, particle)
  instance.x = math.random(20, displayWidth)
  instance.y = math.random(20, displayHeight)
  instance.xVel = math.random(-150, 150)
  instance.yVel = math.random(-150, 150)
  instance.width = 8
  instance.height = 8
  table.insert(ActiveParticle, instance)
end


function particle:draw()
  display.newRect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end

function particle.drawAll()
  for i,instance in ipairs(ActiveParticle) do
    particle:draw()
  end
end

function particle:move()
  self.x = self.x + self.xVel
  self.y = self.y + self.yVel
end

for i = 1, 10 do
  particle.new()
  particle.drawAll()
end

function onUpdate (event)
  instance:move()
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", onUpdate)
```

This code doesn't works, seems solar2d doesn't recognize 'self'.

Comment: what do you mean with doen't work? are you facing errors? or how does the expected behaviour differ from the actual one?

Comment: Yes, i have compilation error. Local instance also doesn't work. Maybe there is different solution to make objects with self parametrs in corona/solora2d?

Comment: and don#t you think it would make sense to share that error message with us?

Comment: main.lua:22 bad argument #1 to 'newRect' (number expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'newRect'
main.lua:22 in function 'draw'
main.lua:27: in function 'drawAll'
main.lua:38: in main chunk

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function particle.new()
  instance = setmetatable({}, particle)
  instance.x = math.random(20, displayWidth)
  instance.y = math.random(20, displayHeight)
  instance.xVel = math.random(-150, 150)
  instance.yVel = math.random(-150, 150)
  instance.width = 8
  instance.height = 8
  table.insert(ActiveParticle, instance)
end
```

`instance` should be local!

Also

```
function particle.drawAll()
  for i,instance in ipairs(ActiveParticle) do
    particle:draw()
  end
end
```

Should use `instance:draw()` as you want to draw the instance not `particle`. Otherwise `self` will not refer to `instance` so you cannot access it's members.

Alternatively use `particle.draw(instance)`

Due to the `__index` metamethod `instance:draw()` will resolve to `particle.draw(instance)` so inside `particle.draw` `self` refers to `instance`